# how to loop through piece of code from current timer to given time using Timer.Timer (or) How to add Timer to loop?

Tags: c#, .net

I have to loop through  code for specified time .I achieved it with DateTime

```
var time=DateTime.Now.AddMinutes((Convert.ToDouble(1)));
while(DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, time) <= 0)
{
  console.write("some message..")
}
```

How do i achieve the same with Timer.Timer or thread.timer which is best approach..

Is it possible to write 10 times per sec?
Can anyone suggest. thank you

Comment: If the question would only exists of "writing 10 times per sec", add a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); under your console.write. The application will wait 1/10'th of a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx), which is accurate and most appropriate for your scenario.

```
Action<long> action = (milliseconds) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running for {0}ms", milliseconds);

    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    while (watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds <= milliseconds)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ticks:{0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    watch.Stop();
};

Task.Run(() => action(1000));
```

[image]

Comment: How can use if want to print 30 messages per millisecond.the count of messages may vary next time may 40.

Comment: Didnt understand your question. You cant be sure x number of events occur in one millisecond.

Comment: I got solution by passing time span=1000/30 value i am able to control messages

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
        int counts = 0;
        timer = new Timer((obj) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(counts);
            if (++counts > 10)
                timer.Dispose();

        }, null, 100, 100);


        for (;;) ;
    }
```

will call the method dosomething() after 100ms, every 100ms
in the background, till timer.Dispose() is called;
this implementation will ofc never terminate as it is written here ;)

[image]

Comment: but it is not loopingthrough.   eg: if i pass 1 minute it should loop through the function for 1 min (say printing 10 msg per second)

Comment: have you put for example a Thread.Sleep(100000); afterwards?
or just a for(;;) ...updated answer...

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to make this work you need to make your program [multithreaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck8bc5c6.aspx),

See [System.Threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [System.Threading.Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Once you have your code executing in it's own thread, (using Thread, Task, Timer or any of the other variations in those namespaces) you can tell it to stop executing for a set amount of time, this is done by calling the Thread.Sleep or Task.Delay methods.

e.g.

```
Task.Run(()=>
{
    do
    {
        //do something
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
    while(! exitCondition)
});
```

however you shouldn't count on this for exact timing as what you are doing is saying to the OS that this thread doesn't need to be executed for that amount of time, it doesn't mean the OS will pass it to the processor immediately on the time running out. depending on how busy the CPU is there can be quite a delay before your thread reaches the top of the waiting to process queue. if the timing is vitally important then i would set a lower time and check the clock before running

Comment: Well for example `System.Timers.Timer` execute Tick event on first available thread from the threadpool so it works in multithreaded environment already there is no need to use `Tasks` to achieve that.

Comment: @Fabjan that would be another method to implementing the multithreading, however i didn't suggest using a time or a background word or any f the other many ways of implementing of it

Comment: I think that OP just wants to understand how timer works.  Sometimes when we work with older versions of .NET framework (like NET 2.0 CF) we simply don't have this luxury of using `Tasks` and `TPL`.